# Filter queryset results based on a boolean field which is True

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filters

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.EmailFiled()

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

We have multiple products. some of them are active=False the other ones are True. I should take the products which is active=true requesting user.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the ability to filter results of a `ViewSet` based on your `active` flag. I highly recommend you to read **[DRF Filtering documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)**

You simply need to add to your `ViewSet` or `APIView` the following fields

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    # Add Filtering Backend
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    # Add filtering fields (Default behavior is to exact match provided values)
    filterset_fields = ['is_active']
```

and now in your request, you should have the query param

```
http://example.com/api/products?is_active=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the `Product`s that are active and in the `Cart` of a user with:

```
Product.objects.filter(is_active=True, cart__order__user=my_user)
```

Comment: but Product model does not have cart field,isnt it? @Wilem Van Onsem

Comment: @OlimhonYusufjonov: it does not *need* to have a `cart` field. This is simply the many-to-many relation in reverse. Django automatically adds this relation.